# Como puedo tener dos metodos de "Res" en Node.JS para evitar Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, nodejs

mi pregunta es, como puedo tener dos res dentro de un mismo app?

Por ejemplo al tener algo similar a esto:

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {  

//Codigo.... 
res.json(respuesta);

//codigo
res.render('./index);
}
```

Y es que necesito hacer afuerzas esos dos dentro de `app.post('/upload', (req, res)` ya que depende de allí la llamada de una API y parsear una respuesta. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo? ya que me regresa el siguiente error: Error `[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿el resultado que vas a enviar es para ser usado por la vista que devuelves? Me refiero a que si ¿es una variable local de la vista?

Answer (score 1):

El objeto res en Express es una subclase de http.ServerResponse de Node.js (lea la fuente http.js). Se le permite llamar a res.setHeader (nombre, valor) con la frecuencia que desee hasta que llame a res.writeHead (statusCode). Después de writeHead, los encabezados son horneados y solo puede llamar a res.write (datos), y finalmente a res.end (datos).

El error "Error: no se pueden establecer los encabezados después de que se envían". significa que ya está en el estado Cuerpo o Finalizado, pero alguna función intentó establecer un encabezado o un código de estado. Cuando vea este error, intente buscar cualquier cosa que intente enviar un encabezado después de que parte del cuerpo ya haya sido escrito. Por ejemplo, busque devoluciones de llamada que se llamen accidentalmente dos veces, o cualquier error que ocurra después de que se envíe el cuerpo.

En su caso, llamó a res.redirect (), lo que provocó que la respuesta se finalizara. Entonces su código arrojó un error (res.req es nulo). y como el error ocurrió dentro de su función real (req, res, next) (no dentro de una devolución de llamada), Connect pudo detectarlo y luego intentó enviar una página de 500 errores. Pero como ya se enviaron los encabezados, setHeader de Node.js arrojó el error que vio.

**Lista completa de los métodos de respuesta Node.js / Express y cuándo deben llamarse:
La respuesta debe estar en Jefe y permanece en Jefe:**

1. res.writeContinue () res.statusCode = 404
2. Elemento de lista
3. Elemento de lista
4. res.setHeader (nombre,valor)
5. res.getHeader (nombre)
6. res.removeHeader (nombre)
7. res.header(clave [, val]) (solo Express)
8. res.charset = 'utf-8' (solo Express;solo afecta los métodos
   específicos de Express)
9. res.contentType(type) (solo Express)

La respuesta debe estar en Cabeza y se convierte en Cuerpo:

- res.writeHead (statusCode, [reasonPhrase], [headers])

La respuesta puede estar en cualquier Cabeza / Cuerpo y permanece en el Cuerpo:

- res.write (fragmento, codificación = 'utf8')

La respuesta puede estar en cualquier Cabeza / Cuerpo y se termina:

- res.end ([datos], [codificación])

La respuesta puede estar en cualquier Cabeza / Cuerpo y permanece en su estado actual:

- res.addTrailers (cabeceras)

La respuesta debe estar en Head y se termina:

volver siguiente ([err]) (Connect / Express solamente)
Cualquier excepción dentro de la función de middleware (req, res, next) (solo Connect / Express)

1. res.send (cuerpo | estado [, encabezados | estado [, estado]]) (solo
   expreso)
2. res.attachment (nombre de archivo) (solo expreso)
3. res.sendfile (ruta [, opciones [, devolución de llamada]]) (solo
   Express)
4. res.json (obj [, headers | status [, status]]) (solo Express)
5. res.redirect (url [, estado]) (solo Express)
6. res.cookie (nombre, val [, opciones]) (solo expreso)
7. res.clearCookie (nombre [, opciones]) (solo Express)
8. res.render (ver [, opciones [, fn]]) (solo Express)
9. res.partial (ver [, opciones]) (solo expreso)